# use conditional proof system for"what can you say about the sets A and B if A ⊕ B = A".

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

what can you say about the sets a and b if A ⊕ B = A?

Given $A⊕B=(A⋃B) - (A⋂B)$ (def 1)

my works:

$1.$ $(∀x)\ ((x∈A∨x∈B) ∧ (x∈A^c ∨x∈B^c )) ⇒(x∈A)$ $\ (\mathrm{premise})$

$2.$ $(∀x)\ (x∈A) ⇒((x∈A∨x∈B) ∧ (x∈A^c ∨x∈B^c))$ $\ (\mathrm{premise})$

---

$3.$ $x∈A$ $\ (\mathrm{assumed})$

$\quad 4.$ $x∈B$ $\ (\mathrm{assumed})$     we discovered that it is not true in statement 2.

$\quad 5.$ $x∉B$

so we can conclude that

$6.$ if $A ⊕ B = A$, then $A≠B$

$7.$ $x∈B$ $\ (\mathrm{assumed})$

$\quad 8.$ $x∈A$ $\ (\mathrm{assumed})$ we discovered that it is not true in statement 2.

$\quad 9.$ $x∉A$ $\ (\mathrm{assumed})$ we discovered that it is not true in statement 1.

$10.$ $x∉B$

So what does $x∉B$ mean in the result?

The only information i got from statement 6 is that set $A$ and $B$ is totally different set,they don't have any intersection.

Comment: In the end you should arrive to $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Berci can i do this?from statement 8,9,x∈B⇒(x∈A∧x∉A ),x∈B⇒x∈∅

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your approach, we can work this way:

[1st part] $x \in A$ --- assumed [a]

$x \in B$ --- temporary assumption,

and we have a contradiction (as per your proof, using 2) above), concluding with:

> $\lnot (x \in B)$.

[2nd part] $\lnot (x \in A)$ --- assumed [b]

$x \in B$ --- temporary assumption,

from which we have $(x \in A \lor x \in B)$, by [Disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction).

In the same way, from $\lnot (x \in A)$ we have: $(x \in A^C \lor x \in B^C)$.

Thus, by [Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) and using [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) with 1) above we have: $x \in A$.

We have again a contradiction, and thus:

> $\lnot (x \in B)$.

Now we use [Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) in the form: $(x \in A) \lor \lnot (x \in A)$ with [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) with [a] and [b] in the two sub-proofs above to conclude with:

> > $\lnot (x \in B)$.

But $x$ was a variable whatever: thus, we may apply [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to conclude with:

> $\forall x \lnot (x \in B)$,

which amounts to saying that: $B = \emptyset$.

All the proof relies on the premise 1) and 2), which are the unwinding of the definition of [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties).

Thus, we may apply [Conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) to have:

> > $(A \Delta B =A) \to B= \emptyset$.

Comment: Is it in any form of  (x∈A)∨¬(x∈A) prove the same result e.g: (x∈D),we can apply Universal Generalization to conclude them as ∀x(x∈D)?

Comment: @LeeSam - ??? not clear... Why $D$ ?

Comment: If we don't have [b] part ,can we conclude that ∀x¬(x∈B)?

Comment: @LeeSam - not exactly; if you remove part [b] you have: $(x \in A \to x \in B)$ and only then you can "generalize" it to get: $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$ which amounts to: $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: I understood it well,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusions aren't clear the way you present them. But you can show that $$A\oplus B = (A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)$$ holds in general. Note that the above union is disjoint.

Now, from the equality $A = (A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)$ conclude that it holds if and only if $A = A\cap B^c$ and $A^c\cap B = \emptyset$. Thus,

$$A = A\cap B^c \implies A\subseteq B^c \implies B\subseteq A^c\implies A^c\cap B = B.$$ Finally, conclude that $B = \emptyset$.

Conversely, show that $B= \emptyset$ implies $A\oplus B = A$, so it is an "if and only if" statement.

Comment: Thanks,but how can we show that B⊆A'⟹A'∩B by deduction principle?

Comment: @Lee Sam, by contradiction. Assume that $B\not\subseteq A^c$. That means that there is a $b\in B$ that is also in $A$, so $b\in A\cap B$. Thus, $A\not\subseteq B^c$.

Comment: @Lee Sam, if you don't like that statement, use $A = A\cap B^c \iff A\cap B = \emptyset$. You will immediately get $A = A \cap B^c \iff B = A^c\cap B$. Or use $A\cap B$ as the intermediate result between $A\subseteq B^c$ and $B\subseteq A^c$.

Comment: but how contradiction A⊈B' related  to A'∩B=B.

Comment: @Lee Sam, it is not, notice that there are three implications in that line that need to be proven separately.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it your question means : how to go from " x does not belong to B " to " B is empty " and finally to " B is identical to the empty set" .

My proof starts where yours ends.

It amounts to showing this basic result : there is one and only one empty set; all empty sets are , in fact, one and the same set.

This is trivial, but not axiomatic, since it can be proved.

The proof makes use of RAA ( reductio ad absurdum) : anything implying a contradiction is false.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed steps,i have learnt a lot,do you have any recommand book for learning this formal proof system so i can master this logic system.